# Randomstream in vba for Arena

Tags: vba, random, arena-simulation

I have been practising my knowledge in Arena, mainly in the VBA module. My intention is to get random data, from a uniform distribution in VBA. I've been testing with the code:

```
Dim s As SIMAN
Set s = ThisDocument.Model.SIMAN
s.SampleUniform (5,10, randomStream As Long)
```

The values 5 and 10 are the minimum and maximum, but the third parameter I have not been able to find a value that is accepted by VBA, it is supposed to be a random value that serves as a seed to generate the uniform value. I have tried with the `Rnd` function but it generates error.

Comment: Remove the parentheses from the arguments (you only need those if there's a return value you want to capture).  Also remove the `As Long`

Comment: Thanks, but yes, i want to save the value in a variable or an atributte, so i need the parenthesis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been looking for examples and found one in which the code is presented as follows:

```
Dim s As SIMAN
Set s = ThisDocument.Model.SIMAN
Int(s.SampleUniform(5, 10, 10))
```

I still don't understand why the randomstream has a value of 10, but the expression works correctly.

Comment: You could leave that 3rd argument (randomstream) out, and you would still get the same answer, since 10 is the default stream. If you prefer to sample from a different stream of random numbers, you could choose a value between 1 and 9.